# How to rewrite complex conditional as pattern matching?

Tags: scala, pattern-matching

Is there a way to rewrite this conditional as a pattern matching?

```
val oldEmail : Option[String]
val newEmail : Option[String]

if (newEmail.isDefined && (oldEmail.isEmpty || newEmail.get != oldEmail.get))
   sendActivationEmail(newEmail.get)
else
   ()
```

my only failed attempt was this:

```
(newEmail, oldEmail) match {
    case (Some(_), None) | (Some(ne), Some(oe)) if ne != oe =>
        sendActivationEmail(newEmail.get)
    case _ => ()
}
```

**Edit:** I should explicitly mention that my goal is a pattern matching with only two case clauses as shown above, for it's learning value

Comment: Why is `newEmail` an `Option` if it's always supposed to be defined?

Comment: I'm only asking this question for it's learning value. :P

Comment: @Ryan actually if it's undefined, no activation email will be sent

Comment: You could also rewrite your conditional as `if (newEmail.exists(ne => !oldEmail.contains(ne)))` to avoid using the (in itself) unsafe `.get`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That logic does make for a rather complicated pattern. I'd be tempted to skip pattern matching.

```
newEmail.collect{
  case ne if oldEmail.fold(true)(_ != ne) => sendActivationEmail(ne)
}
```

**Update**  incorporating worthy input from @Alexey and @Cyrille Corpet and a suggestion from the IntelliJ IDE. (peer review ;-)

```
newEmail.foreach(ne => if (!oldEmail.contains(ne)) sendActivationEmail(ne))
```

Comment: This is really pretty. no short circuit dependant ```.get``` calls, short and elegant. this was my ultimate goal.

Comment: I'm not sure why use `collect` here.
I believe this is a bit more concise: `newEmail.foreach{
  ne => if (oldEmail.fold(true)(_ != ne)) sendActivationEmail(ne)
}`

Comment: @Alexey ```collect``` automatically handles the case for which the partial function is not defined at, returning a ```None```. whereas in ```foreach``` you'll get a runtime exception if you don't account for the ```case _ => ()``` as well

Comment: @Alexey, very true. I had the `if` condition on the other side of the `=>` which meant I needed a default `case _ =>` when using `foreach` instead of `collect`. Yours is more concise but it does use an `if` without an `else` which, in this case, is probably justified.

Comment: @shayan you might be correct in the general case of pattern matching, but as I dropped the `case` altogether here, your example isn't relevant for my solution.
`collect` is useful for the cases, where you want to only keep objects which fall under some pattern matching, without specifying the negative cases.
But here, you don't need to have the expression returning anything, that's why `foreach` looks more appropriate...

Comment: `oldEmail.fold(true)(_ != ne)` can be rewritten as `oldEmail.forall(_ != ne)`

Answer (score 1):

You can have multiple pattern matches as below,

```
test("given empty old email sends email to new email") {
  val oldEmailOpt : Option[String] = None
  val newEmailOpt : Option[String] = Some("this-is-my-beatifool email")

  val result = newEmailOpt match {
    case Some(newEmail) => oldEmailOpt match {
      case Some(oldEmail) if !newEmail.equals(oldEmail) => "send email to new email"
      case None => "send email to new email"
    }
    case None => "sending email to new email"
  }

  result shouldBe "send email to new email"
}
```

Comment: I only send activation email to the new submitted email in my example. but I get your point.

Comment: @shayan why does old-email exists then? I updated the example though

Comment: Long story short. our registeration implementation doesn't require email for activation on all cases. sometimes if user registers with oauth2 it's account is automatically activated

Comment: you see my goal was to reach a more elegant solution than than those short circuit depentant ```.get``` calls inside conditional clause. your solution while correct is still quite verbose. but ty

Comment: I know, this is a terrible solution :). That `.collect.fold` is super cool solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can make the pattern match work by having two different matches, but unless you're just calling the same method, there's some unwanted code duplication:

```
def f2(newEmail:Option[String], oldEmail:Option[String]) =
  (newEmail, oldEmail) match {
    case (Some(ne), None) =>
        sendActivationEmail(ne)
    case (Some(ne), Some(oe)) if ne != oe =>
        sendActivationEmail(ne)
    case _ =>
         ()
  }
```